# Passing get variable into function as "criteria" (imap_sort)

Tags: php

Trying to find a way to pass the variable as the criteria

```
$_GET['sort'] = (@!$_GET['sort']) ? SORTARRIVAL : SORT . $_GET['sort'];
$sort = imap_sort ($inbox, $_GET['sort'] , 1, SE_UID);
```

if I pass a url such as .../?sort=SUBJECT

I get an error.

> Warning: imap_sort() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Comment: You pass SORT as a string; SORTARRIVAL and such are actually constants which have an integer value (i.e. 1, 2, 3, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your $_GET value is a string containing the *name* of the constant you want to use, and imap expects the *value* of the constant, you need to turn one into the other (ie. you say "SORTARRIVAL" while imap expects the *value* of SORTARRIVAL (which is something like 1 or 2 or 3 or whatever).

You can look up a constant using the constant() function like so:

```
if(isset($_GET['sort']) && constant('SORT' . $_GET['sort']) !== null) {
   // we check if we have a value in $_GET['sort'] and also check if a constant with that name exists
   $sort = constant('SORT' . $_GET['sort'])
} else {
   // default value in case the constant didn't exist or $_GET['sort'] was empty
   $sort = SORTARRIVAL;
}
$sort = imap_sort ($inbox, $sort, 1, SE_UID);
```